# Is FreeRTOS (and other RTOS'es) also a framework

Tags: c++, c, frameworks, rtos, freertos

As we know FreeRTOS is a real-time operating system.

For example, if we take explanation from wiki:

[Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework).

FreeRTOS has something we may call "inversion-of-control" - FreeRTOS controls all the tasks implemented by programmer.
Also FreeRTOS is extensible.
The problem with this definition is when we take "non-modifiable framework code" - FreeRTOS is deployed mainly as source code for user project - you can modify it.

Is FreeRTOS a framework?
And are there better definitions for frameworks?

Comment: As "Framework" is a concept, you need to ask "Framework for what?"  FreeRTOS could be part of a framework for delivering a real-time operating system application development environment for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, FreeRTOS, as most other RTOS kernels, is just a toolkit, not a framework. This is because **you** need to write the body of each task, typically as an endless loop. You then decide which RTOS blocking mechanisms (semaphores, time-delays, event-flags, etc.) to use to "throttle" the execution of your task body.

In a framework, you typically would not do this. The framework would provide the body of your tasks and would also provide the blocking mechanism. For example, a framework might structure every task as an event loop (a.k.a. "message-pump") with a message queue. Then the framework will call **your** code to handle every event. This is how the **inversion of control** (a defining characteristic of a framework) comes about.

Please note that an RTOS *can* be used as a component of a framework, but an RTOS itself is not a framework.